# Transaction Check Error when installing ImageMagick-devel

Tags: imagemagick, fedora, yum, libtiff

I'm trying to install the RMagick gem on a Fedora box.  To do so I need to install ImageMagick-devel.  While installing ImageMagick-devel, I ran into the following error:

```
Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/lib64/libtiff.so from install of libtiff-devel-3.9.4-21.el6_8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libtiff4-4.0.3-1.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/libtiffxx.so from install of libtiff-devel-3.9.4-21.el6_8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libtiff4-4.0.3-1.x86_64
```

I tried removing libtiff but this did not make a difference.  It seems like a fairly common issue, but all the suggestions I've tried have not worked.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to remove the duplicate version of libtiff using:

```
sudo rpm -e libtiff4-4.0.3-1.x86_64
```